# Restoring a PostgreSQL/PostGIS backup into a new database with fresh extensions

Tags: postgis, postgresql, migration, upgrade

I'm working on a migration from a very old server (Ubuntu 10.04/Postgres 8.x, etc) to a new instance (18.04) with up-to-date versions of everything in our web stack.

Our PostgreSQL database uses a few extensions—notably PostGIS and fuzzystrmatch—as well as several custom functions. Probably pretty typical.

I expect a `pg_dump` like this..

```
pg_dump -U username -h 127.0.0.1 dbname > dbname.backup.sql
```

..will include everything: extensions, custom functions, and data. But, I don't want the old extensions.

If I initially create a same-named, but empty db, like this..

```
createdb -U postgres -T template0 --owner=dbowner dbname
```

..then manually add the extensions like this..

```
psql -p 5432
\connect dbname;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;
CREATE EXTENSION ogr_fdw;
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_tiger_geocoder;
\q
```

..so that everything is recent and up-to-date..

**Will a db restore from the** `.sql` **file created from a vanilla** `pg_dump`, **like above, actually overwrite** (a'la `CREATE OR REPLACE`) **any same-named functions in the new extensions?**

I'm starting to assume so, and I'm re-thinking this.

**tl;dr**
Is the best way to do this to first invoke the `--data-only` option in `pg_dump` for our db backup, then build our new, same-named schema manually, individually add our custom functions, then import the data-only `.sql` file?

FWIW I'm hoping to avoid that ^ approach, because I don't want to overlook any of our custom functions by moving them manually. While many of them have a prefix signalling our organization, unfortunately, some don't. Furthermore, I'm concerned if I do a whole db restore, then try to upgrade the extensions, the upgrade process will be painful because the source db/extension versions are so out-of-date to begin with.

Comment: Personally I'd go with a data only dump that you can also use otherwise, and a fresh setup. PosgreSQL has undergone significant changes between 3 major versions, and it would actually be necessary for PostGIS < 2.0 due to the different extension implementations (more e.g. [here](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2016/08/postgis-upgrade.html))! And you could at least try to get your functions by owner/role...if those were not created by the superuser.